# InnoDB foreign key definition cannot resolve column name

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I have a problem creating a foreign key constraint between two tables.

Here is the first table:

```
CREATE TABLE `agews_rifiuti_cer` (
  `id_cer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `agews_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `livello` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `codice` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descrizione` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `note` text,
  `flag_pericoloso` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `id_cliente` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `flag_modificato` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cer`),
  KEY `fk_id_cliente_agews_sgs_codici_cer` (`id_cliente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And here is the second one:

```
CREATE TABLE `lin_98_47_rifiuti` (
  `id_rifiuto` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_azienda` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `id_sede` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `revisione_documento` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rifiuto` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codice_cer` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome_interno` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descrizione` text,
  `materie_prime` text,
  `contenitore` text,
  `deposito` text,
  `data_ultima_analisi` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `stato_fisico` enum('Solido pulverulento','Solido non pulverulento','Fangoso palabile','Liquido') DEFAULT 'Solido non pulverulento',
  `quantita` float(9,1) DEFAULT '0.0',
  `unita_misura` enum('Kg','l','mc') DEFAULT 'Kg',
  `id_pericolo` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `destino` enum('Recupero','Smaltimento') DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_recupero` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_smaltimento` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_cer` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `immagine` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_content` mediumblob,
  `image_size_x` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `image_size_y` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `flag_storico` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `id_responsabile` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `nome_responsabile` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `id_ultima_modifica` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `create_log` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_rifiuto`,`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
  KEY `fk_main_lin_98_47_rifiuti` (`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`),
  KEY `fk_id_responsabile_lin_98_47_rifiuti` (`id_responsabile`,`id_azienda`,`id_sede`,`revisione_documento`,`nome_responsabile`),
  KEY `fk_id_pericolo_lin_98_47_rifiuti` (`id_pericolo`),
  KEY `fk_id_recupero_lin_98_47_rifiuti` (`id_recupero`),
  KEY `fk_id_smaltimento_lin_98_47_rifiuti` (`id_smaltimento`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The problem happens the I try to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE lin_98_47_rifiuti ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_cer_lin_98_47_rifiuti FOREIGN KEY (id_cer) REFERENCES agews_rifiuti_cer(id_cer) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And I get this error:

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'db_626suite.#sql-71c_13d5' (errno: 150)
```

While the command SHOW INNODB STATUS says:

```
Error in foreign key constraint of table db_626suite/#sql-71c_13d5:
 FOREIGN KEY (id_cer) REFERENCES agews_rifiuti_cer(id_cer) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE:
Cannot resolve column name close to:
) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But the syntax and fields definitions seem correct to me. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

**Marc B** suggested that it could be due to the fact that `id_cer` is defined as `NOT NULL` in `agews_rifiuti_cer`, but I do not think this is the case, in fact please consider this other table:

```
CREATE TABLE `agews_rifiuti_pericolo` (
  `id_pericolo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `agews_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `codice` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pericolo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `note` text,
  `id_cliente` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  `flag_modificato` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pericolo`),
  KEY `codice_rifiuti_recupero` (`codice`),
  KEY `fk_id_cliente_rifiuti_pericolo` (`id_cliente`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here `id_pericolo` is defined as `NOT NULL` as `id_cer` above, and yet this works perfectly:

```
ALTER TABLE lin_98_47_rifiuti ADD CONSTRAINT fk_id_pericolo_lin_98_47_rifiuti FOREIGN KEY (id_pericolo) REFERENCES agews_rifiuti_pericolo(id_pericolo) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

even if in `lin_98_47_rifiuti` the field `id_pericolo` is defined as `DEFAULT NULL`

EDIT 2:

I just tried this minimal setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `cer` (
  `id_cer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codice` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `rifiuti` (
  `id_rifiuto` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_cer` int(10) unsigned NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `rifiuto` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_rifiuto`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE rifiuti ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_cer) REFERENCES cer(id_cer) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

and it all worked correctly, yet I do not understand what the problem might be in my original query.

Also I think this proves that is not a matter of defining the fields as `NOT NULL` or `DEFAULT NULL`.

Comment: What kind of minimal sample would you need? Here is not a matter of inserting data, is just mere table definition, and I've given all the specs.

Comment: A similar insert on a table that has only the columns necessary to cause the problem. You might even find the solution yourself when you are setting that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really do not understand **why**, but renaming `id_cer` to `id_codice` in all tables, while leaving its definition unaltered, has solved the problem.

So it would seem that MySQL had some kind of problem with that specific field name.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined `id_cer` as `default null` in the lin_98_47 table, but the matching FK field in the other table is defined as `not null`.

The field definitions have to match EXACTLY for a foreign key relationship to be established, and that includes nullability:

```
`id_cer` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`id_cer` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

Comment: I do not think this is the case, see my edit. Also, this is somethink I've done hundreds of times...